# mysql order_by question

Tags: sql, mysql

Query table articles:

```
select * from articles where article_id in(98,97,96,99)
```

returned result ordered like

```
record 96 ...
record 97 ...
record 98 ...
record 99 ...
```

but I prefer the result ordered the same as 'in(98,97,96,99)'. Any tricks to make it possible?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you say a bit more about the 'problem domain'?  Is the IN list different on every query?  Pulling back hundreds of rows using an IN list wont scale that far, regardless of the ORDER BY side of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IN function is subject to a limit on the size of the list.  More likely, once the list gets to a few hundred entries, your performance will drop off - you may as well retrieve the records individually and sort them in the client.

Having said that, there's another MySQL function, [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) you might consider to implement your ORDER BY.  FIND_IN_SET can only handle up to 64 members in the set though.

```
ORDER BY
    FIND_IN_SET( article_id, '98,97,96,99' )
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this might work:

```
select * from articles where article_id in(98,97,96) order by article_id desc
union
select * from articles where article_id = 99
```

I can't see any pattern to your ordering so I can't think of any other way to do this.

Comment: This looks not scalable to me, coz the article_id sequence's order could be random as you said no pattern.

Comment: 96,97,98,99 looks like a pattern to me!

Comment: @Shawn: If you want it scalable, you could build the query string dynamically:
$query="select * from articles where article_id in(".$in_list_1.") order by article_id ".$order1."
union
select * from articles where article_id in (."$in_list_2".) order by article_id ".$order2

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: You way should work but looks too dirty tho. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Shawn, When you use IN Statement, in MYSQL

It compares the First record ID to your given ID.
Then compares Second record ID to your given ID.
So ...

So the result will be displayed in asc order.

If you need dont use IN statement. I would prefer to Retrieve Each record in loop.

Thankyou

Comment: Yes thought about that but still not scalable, I can have hundreds of id's in the 'in' statement, don't think putting query into a loop is a good idea. Thanks tho.

Comment: Definitely that will make the process quite slow. But IN Statement not supports that you have mention

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do something like this:

```
select * from articles where article_id in(98,97,96,99) order by article_id == 98 desc, article_id == 97 desc, article_id == 96 desc, article_id == 99 desc;
```

Comment: Not scalable. If I got 500 id's the query may grow fat.